# Is it possible to approximate when will kmean finish?

Tags: performance, cluster-analysis, k-means

Sorry for the weird question, but the thing is I am running kmeans, using [Yael library](https://gforge.inria.fr/projects/yael/).

I got myself about 9,000,000 vectors of 128 dimensions and I am going for 1,000,000 centroids. It is running on 24 cores CPU, and it is running for many hours now. This is my first time running kmeans with this huge amount of data, and I want to know when it will finish, rather than waiting for it to finish and know later.

So the question is, is it possible to approximate when will kmean finish?

Comment: sorry, now I get your question. I deleted my answer for that. there's no way to know when it'll finish not even to close to the real time. because there are many factors here and you can never know them all :)  but I can say it'll take to much time so cheer up and leave it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that

A) the algorithm is appropriate for your problem? k-means is built in a lot of assumptions, in particular that your clusters have the same size

B) that your parameters make any sense? Is a "clustering" into "1000000" of any *use*? Does it make sense? How many of these clusters will end up containing just 0 or 1 observations?

A naive k-means implementation (and 99% are naive) will use `O(n*k*i)` where `n` is the number of observations, `k` is the number of clusters and `i` is the number of required iterations until convergence. So *obviously* it scales badly to 1000000 clusters.
But even worse: k-means will in the worst case test `O(k^n)` assignments. Usually much less, but obviously this number is highly dependant on the number of clusters. So the more clusters, the more iterations you will usually need until convergence!